# gxt grid: span column header over multiple columns

Tags: css, gwt, grid, gxt

I have gxt grid in my web app. I want the caption of one column header to span over multiple columns.

```
    |column1  |column2  |loooooooooooong text|column5
    _________________________________________________
    |aaaaaaaaa|bbbbbbbbb|ccccccccc|dddddddddd|eeeeeee
```

The header is a one-row table. Each cell has a div with a span.
div inherits styles:
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;

I tried to change it to
overflow: visible;
text-overflow: none;

but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a HeaderGroup. Look at these for an example  http://www.sencha.com/examples/#columngrouping